# Code coverage for angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, code-coverage

How do you find the code coverage for angular 2 code? Is there any plugin for vs code editor or webstorm that I can use? I am using Jasmine and Karma for unit testing of my code.

Comment: I can, of course, see the extensions online. I wanted to understand which one is better, tried and tested by the developers. If I may ask, why do you think it is not encouraged?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to see overall test coverage statistics than of course in Angular CLI you can just type, and see the bottom of your command prompt window

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

result:

[image: console view of tests coverage]

if you want to see component's individual coverage of tests follow these steps.

1. `npm install --save-dev karma-teamcity-reporter`
2. Add `require('karma-teamcity-reporter')` to list of plugins in karma.conf.js
3. `ng test --code-coverage --reporters=teamcity,coverage-istanbul`

note that list of reporters is comma-separated, as we have added a new reporter, teamcity.

after running this command you can see the folder `coverage` in your dir and open `index.html` for a graphical view of test coverage.

[image]

You can also set the coverage threshold that you want to achieve, in `karma.conf.js`, like this.

```
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      thresholds: {
        statements: 90,
        lines: 90,
        branches: 90,
        functions: 90
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 7):

First install the dependencies.

```
npm install karma karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher karma-jasmine-html-reporter karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter
```

Then run ng test.

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

Then run the server that shows you your report.

```
http-server -c-1 -o -p 9875 ./coverage
```

You should see something like this:

[image]

I wrote a blog post about this [here](https://www.codewithjason.com/add-test-coverage-report-angular-cli-project/).

Comment: Just perfect no extra no less

Comment: You could also just open index.html in the "coverage" folder if you want something really quick.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one. The solution I found was

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

But make sure that in your karma.conf.js file, you have a reporter specified (I use 'coverage-istanbul')

e.g. `reporters: ['coverage-istanbul']`

The coverage report will be in a directory called 'coverage' in your root directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

or

```
ng test --code-coverage --reporters=teamcity,coverage-istanbul
```